# Zstack read attribute

Tags: attributes, zigbee

I want to know how can I read some attribute on local and remote zigbee device using TI zstack and how to put its value to uart. I'm zstack beginner. I managed to use uart with usb to uart converter and can send data to my pc. So I need to know how to get the attribute data. I've read api manual but didn't anderstand how to use zcl_SendRead function. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow section "3.3 Send Read" of the "Z-Stack ZCL API.pdf" this should contain enough info for getting the read attr to the correct destination device. The contents of the readCmd is an array of attribute ID's, specific to the attribute(s) you want to read. You will need to consult the ZCL specification or device documentation to determine the correct Attr ID and Cluster ID.

An example for sending a read attr is shown below. It reads the ATTRID_MS_TEMPERATURE_MEASURED_VALUE attribute (from the ZCL_CLUSTER_ID_MS_TEMPERATURE_MEASUREMENT cluster) from device with short address 0x1234 and endpoint 0x1.

```
afAddrType_t dstAddr;
dstAddr.addrMode = afAddr16Bit;
dstAddr.addr.shortAddr = 0x1234; //set this to correct address
dstAddr.addr.endPoint = 0x1; // set this to correct ep

zclReadCmd_t *cmd = osal_mem_alloc((sizeof zclReadCmd_t) + sizeof(uint16));
cmd->numAttr = 1;
cmd->attrID[0] = ATTRID_MS_TEMPERATURE_MEASURED_VALUE;

zcl_SendRead( SAMPLETHERMOSTAT_ENDPOINT, &dstAddr,
ZCL_CLUSTER_ID_MS_TEMPERATURE_MEASUREMENT, 
&cmd, ZCL_FRAME_CLIENT_SERVER_DIR, 
hdr->fc.disableDefaultRsp, hdr->transSeqNum );
```

Once this command is sent you need to process the received the response, you will notice that the functions are contained in the ZStack Sample Applications but not populated, for instance the SampleSwitch application has zclSampleSw_ProcessInReadRspCmd() function, this will be called to process the read attr response and you will need to populate it to do what you want to do with the response.

Regards,
TC.